# Cannot assign value of type 'Foundation.Data' to type 'Appname.Data'

Tags: swift, image, foundation, imagedata

I have code for fetching the image data.The same code works fine in other projects but in this project i am getting this error.The code which causes the error is as given below:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL
                   let imagePath =  imageURL?.path
                   print("imagepath is",imagePath)
             _ = imageURL?.lastPathComponent
              
                    // self.camimgname = imageName
                  //  self.finalimgname = self.camimgname
                      var  chosenImage = UIImage()
                      chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage //2
                      self.profileimg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
                      self.profileimg.image = chosenImage //4
                     
             if let data = chosenImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                       
                      // self.camdata = data
                        self.imgdata = data
                   }
                        
                      dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
            }
```

The screenshot of the error is as given below:

[image]

What could be the issue with this Data.Is there any unwanted framework added or anything?

Comment: Show your declaration for `imgdata` and do you have a module type of `Data` ?

Comment: The error message is clear. You have defined a type called Data. Don’t do that. Swift already has a type by that name.

Comment: @WarrenBurton     var imgdata: Data!